# How to install commons-lang src to local repository?

Tags: java, maven-2, apache-commons-lang

I want to use the commons-lang by maven,but apache repository isn't ,I down commons-lang-src publish in local repository ,but is warning.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.4.3:test (default-test) on project commons-lang: There are test failures.
```

how to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the way to do it. As you can see in [this maven mirror listing](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.5/), the commons/lang sources are already available in all maven repositories that mirror central, so there is no need to build them yourself (BTW: if you build the project, you are installing the compiled binaries, not the sources, so even a success wouldn't have helped you).

Here's how to do it (Assuming you use eclipse):

1. If you use [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/), just right-click the project and select `Maven -> Download Sources`
2. If you use the [maven-eclipse-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) see the page about [adding sources to libs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/examples/attach-library-sources.html)

If you don't use eclipse, I know there are similar plugins for NetBeans and IntelliJ Idea.

Answer (score 2):

There are commons-lang binaries at repo1.maven.org.

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/

Why don't use this?

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to @seanizer's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599472/how-to-install-commons-lang-src-to-local-repository/3599589#3599589), the command line solution is to use `dependency:sources` goal from the [Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/):

> [`dependency:sources`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/sources-mojo.html) tells Maven to resolve all dependencies and their source attachments, and displays the version.

So just run the following against your project on the command line

```
mvn dependency:sources
```

And maven will download the sources of dependencies, if they exist.